# how to make ddslick popup overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use ddSlick jquery plug-in(a drop down with images) on my page. I'm trying to add this dropdown plug-in into a panel with size Height:200 to Widht:100px.

The problem comes when i clicked on the drop down, the popup menu goes under the other page elements. So last part of the dropdown popup can not be shown to the user.

Please let me know how can I make sure these kind of widgets get to overflow on other page elements?

Thanks,

Comment: z-index is the answer and position: absolute

Comment: @Hardy yes, i set the position and z-index of the div element and it works now. If you reply i will set your reply as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your element **z-index** css property. Z-index handles 
elements position in z-axis. z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).